# How to use MYSQL on dates formatted as MM/dd/yy

Tags: mysql, vb.net, date

I  have a database full of dates that are in the format: MM/dd/yy. For example, today's date (November 4, 2011) is saved in the database as: 11/04/11. I'm having trouble with date ranges since my dates aren't formatted as yyyy/MM/dd (example: 2011/11/04). I don't have a way to change the way the database is populated, so I need to account for the date formatting differences within my MYSQL queries (via VB.NET). Here is my query (it doesn't work well because the dates are in the incorrect format):

```
SELECT CMP_DATE FROM my_data WHERE OBJ_DATE >= '1994/01/01' AND CMP_DATE <= '2011/11/04'
```

Is there anyway to reformat the dates within the query? Thank you.

Comment: You may want to clarify what data type they are stored as. I am guessing there are text rather than an actually date type?

Comment: For those wishing to repeat Y2K: what year is `10/04/50`? 1950 or 2050?

Comment: @Piskvor that is a perfect point raised.

Comment: @aayush sharma: Thank you - people keep forgetting why this is important once the catastrophe is averted. Note that both are realistic dates - e.g. birthdate and contract expiration - but it's impossible to tell just from the date.

Comment: @Piskvor yeah but i mean for his case maybe it does not matter and like he is using that field as a text field then his query should be running fine right?

Comment: not sure if you need MM/dd/yy or yyyy/mm/dd `STR_TO_DATE('02/20/99', '%m/%d/%Y')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you need is [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

```
SELECT CMP_DATE
FROM my_data
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(OBJ_DATE, '%d/%m/%y') >= '1994-01-01'
AND STR_TO_DATE(CMP_DATE, '%d/%m/%y') <= '2011-11-04'
```

[@Piskvor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19746/piskvor) has a good point, too, you should consider interpreting the 2-digit year yourself, instead of letting mysql perform some arbitrary conversion.

Comment: STR_TO_DATE results in a null. :\

Comment: Please have a look at the documentation of the function: "If the date, time, or datetime value extracted from str is illegal, `STR_TO_DATE()` returns `NULL` and produces a warning"